# Gridview and List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using gridview control to display records. i am using System.Collections.Generic List<> as datasource. I want to perform sort operation in gridview. Please help me

Comment: Sort as in real time sort ( Click on GUI and sort), or pro grammatically sort?

Comment: Click on gridview header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial -

[Sorting GridView Using IComparer](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/203_Sorting_GridView_Using_IComparer.aspx)

In summary you can use the IComparable interface to define a custom sorting depending on what column heading you click.

Hope this helps.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

Setting AllowSorting property to true should be enough. Are you looking for custom sort?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically,

You may need to sort the `List<>` before bind to gridview.

Or you may need to cast the `gridview.DataSource` to `List<>` explicitly and sort it.

If you want to sort the gridview on your GUI, then you need to set the [`gridview.AllowSorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx) property to `true`, then you should be able to sort.

Comment: What guarantee is there the original `DataSource` is a `List<>` at all? What guarantee is there that it will remain the same type throughout the framework futures?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the data to a BindingSource, then bind the BindingSource to the grid, you should see it update properly when you sort, I believe.